# RegEx to remove non-digit and non-decimal point from string

Tags: java, regex

```
String str = "$1,234.56"
str.replaceAll("[^//d]", "");
```

Desired Output:

```
1234.56
```

Bit lost on how to say keep the decimal point (`.`).

Comment: You are using the wrong kind of slash. You should just add a `.` into the character class: `[^\\d.]`

Comment: Thank you, this was also correct. Preferred the answer with the `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]+", "");
```

`[^\\d.]` is negated character class that will match any character except digit or dot.

Added `+` to make this bit more efficient.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S5NH9m/4)

Comment: Thanks, rank doesn't really matter much in this :)